# How to do use Google Container Registry with the docker CLI

Tags: google-container-registry

[Google Container Registry documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tools/container-registry/) explains that in order to pull and push images to gcr.io, you have to prefix docker `push` and `pull` commands with `gcloud preview`.

```
gcloud preview docker push gcr.io/<gcr_namespace>/<docker-image>
gcloud preview docker pull gcr.io/<gcr_namespace>/<docker-image>
```

Is there a way to use Google Container Registry with the `docker` CLI directly, without `gcloud preview` prefix?

Comment: Just for posterity's sake, the command is now `gcloud docker [push|pull] ...` you don't need `preview` anymore.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following commands:

```
gcloud preview docker -a
```

to update your local docker configuration w/ gcr.io credentials.

And then use the regular `docker` CLI commands to push and pull images:

```
docker build -t gcr.io/<gcr_namespace>/<docker-image> .
docker push gcr.io/<gcr_namespace>/<docker-image>
```

Or for existing images:

```
docker tag <docker-image> gcr.io/<gcr_namespace>/<docker-image>
docker push gcr.io/<gcr_namespace>/<docker-image>
docker pull gcr.io/<gcr_namespace>/<docker-image>
```

This configuration is good for interoperability with the native docker CLI, but not ideal as `gcloud preview docker -a` will need to be run again after the credentials expires.

Comment: This route is mainly useful when wanting to upload an existing image, or an image that is going to be uploaded to multiple registries. by using the docker tag command, you create multiple names to the same image.

Comment: Is there a way to create permanent credentials? Things like Mesos/Marathon expect credentials to be available in `~/.dockercfg`.

Comment: You can use `gcloud preview docker push` to push with updated credentials.

Comment: Yes, I understand that's the right command for pushing images, but when [deploying a docker container on a Mesos cluster](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/docker-containerizer/), Mesos will pull the image himself, relying on the `~/.dockercfg` credentials. Could it be possible to run `gcloud preview docker -a` in cron to keep the credentials valid?

Comment: @Federico, yes IIRC [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/) is (or will be) doing something similar. I don't know if mesos provide hooks before pull/pushing containers that's also something you could explore.

Comment: @Frederico did you ever find this? I still don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

When building a new image, tag it directly to gcr.io during a docker build:

```
gcloud preview docker -a
docker build -t gcr.io/<project_id>/<docker-image> <directory>
push gcr.io/<project_id>/<docker-image>
```